# Sankey plot link splitting - is it possible to have two links flow from one node?

Tags: r, plot, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I want to alter the Sankey plot I made using networkD3 R package so that multiple links flow from one node, here is what I did so far:

header of random sample of data:

```
  Study       Category      Class
  <chr>       <chr>         <chr>                    
1 study17     cat H         class B;class C         
2 study32     cat A;cat B   class A                  
3 study7      cat F         class A                  
4 study21     cat F         class C                  
5 study24     cat F         class B;class C         
6 study15     cat E;cat K   class C   

# example data
d <- read.csv(text = "Study,Category,Class
study17,cat H,class B;class C
study32,cat A;cat B,class A
study7,cat F,class A
study21,cat F,class C
study24,cat F,class B;class C
study15,cat E;cat K,class C")
```

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237151/6938000) I created the following sankeyplot:

[image]

However, as you can tell, the second and third columns now include "composite nodes" such as "cat A;cat B" and "class B; class C".

I would like to make it such that 2 nodes flow from study 32: one to cat A and one to cat B. Similarly, I would like two nodes flowing from cat F (row5): one to class B and one to class C.

In essence, I am asking if something like link splitting is possible? I know I could just split them regularly and create a new row for each instance, but this would distort the truth in this image..

Comment: @zx8754 read the last sentence :)

Comment: Oops, gave up on last paragraph... Why would it distort the truth?

Comment: as it would suggest a new row for the first column as well, and the amount of row is vital information here...

Comment: your original data include "cat A;cat B", so that's what you get in the plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can update the size of rectangles *value* based on split. This should avoid distorting the truth.

```
library(networkD3)
library(data.table)

setDT(d)
# make links
links <- rbind(d[, .(source = Study, target = Category) ],
               d[, .(source = Category, target = Class) ])
links[, rn := .I]
# adjust value, based on "split"
links <- links[, strsplit(source, split = ";", fixed = TRUE), by = .(source, target, rn)
               ][, .(source = V1, target, rn)
                 ][, strsplit(target, split = ";", fixed = TRUE), by = .(source, target, rn) 
                   ][, .(source, target = V1, rn)
                     ][, .(source, target, value = 1/.N), by = rn]
# make nodes
nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(unlist(links[,.(source, target)])))
nodes$label <- nodes$name

# update link ids
links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

# plot
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = 'source_id',
              Target = 'target_id', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'label')
```

[image]

Comment: your solution is brilliant, thanks a lot! Small question, when I use my own non-anonymized  data I get the following error: ```Error in .(source = Study, target = Category) : 
  could not find function "."```  - Any idea why this is?

Comment: @DeMelkbroer I am using data.table. Convert your data to data.table: `setDT(myData)`

Comment: fixed it! You're a legend

Comment: In the above plot, is there a way to not show cat K in second column. However, still show study 15 going to cat K (just a little flow at the beginning). In other words, I would like to remove cat K from the plot but still show there are some observations that go from study 15 to cat K. Is it possible to do in R?

Comment: @Hello post a new question, and link to this post.

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is what you have done already...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(networkD3)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Study,       ~Category,      ~Class,
  "study17",    "cat H",        "class B;class C",
  "study32",    "cat A;cat B",  "class A",
  "study7",     "cat F",        "class A",
  "study21",    "cat F",        "class C",
  "study24",    "cat F",        "class B;class C",
  "study15",    "cat E;cat K",  "class C"
)

links <-
  data %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%  # add a row id
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "column", values_to = "source") %>%  # gather all columns
  mutate(column = match(column, names(data))) %>%  # convert col names to col ids
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(target = lead(source, order_by = column)) %>%  # get target from following node in row
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(target)) %>%  # remove links from last column in original data
  mutate(source = paste0(source, '_', column)) %>%
  mutate(target = paste0(target, '_', column + 1)) %>%
  select(source, target)

nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(links$source, links$target)))
nodes$label <- sub('_[0-9]*$', '', nodes$name) # remove column id from node label

links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1
links$value <- 1

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = 'source_id',
              Target = 'target_id', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'label')
```

### [image]

you could reshape your original data like this

```r
data2 <- data %>% tidyr::separate_rows(everything(), sep = ";")
data2
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    Study   Category Class  
#>    <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  
#>  1 study17 cat H    class B
#>  2 study17 cat H    class C
#>  3 study32 cat A    class A
#>  4 study32 cat B    class A
#>  5 study7  cat F    class A
#>  6 study21 cat F    class C
#>  7 study24 cat F    class B
#>  8 study24 cat F    class C
#>  9 study15 cat E    class C
#> 10 study15 cat K    class C

links <-
  data2 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%  # add a row id
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "column", values_to = "source") %>%  # gather all columns
  mutate(column = match(column, names(data2))) %>%  # convert col names to col ids
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(target = lead(source, order_by = column)) %>%  # get target from following node in row
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(target)) %>%  # remove links from last column in original data
  mutate(source = paste0(source, '_', column)) %>%
  mutate(target = paste0(target, '_', column + 1)) %>%
  select(source, target)

nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(links$source, links$target)))
nodes$label <- sub('_[0-9]*$', '', nodes$name) # remove column id from node label

links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1
links$value <- 1

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = 'source_id',
              Target = 'target_id', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'label')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for assisting but as you can see above @zx8754 answer was better suited for my case